# AWS EC2 linux cant boot

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

After adding an elastic ip my ec2 linux server cannot boot. I'm trying to access it in many ways, without success.

Relevant messages in log:

Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.

Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.

Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... Warning: overlayroot: debug is busted

/bin/sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off

[35969590.173501] random: nonblocking pool is initialized

Is there any way to restore it or access the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, you can get access to the files by:

1. stop your instance
2. detach the volume
3. create new instance (with it's own volume of course)
4. attach the volume from your problematic instance to the new instance
5. mount it to `/mnt/something` or where ever you want and you will have access to your data. The question is how to fix it so that you could boot from that volume. Have a look at /sbin/init and see if it's there.

Also, I doubt that the only change you made is associate an elastics ip.. Explain what exactly did you do.

Comment: I'm afraid of having forced the reboot after a long delay for the amazon processing but I'm not sure ...

Comment: A corrupted `/sbin/init` would explained it, or issue with the file system .. That's why we should always snapshot our instances - backup is really important.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you 13nilux.

I doubt it too, but that's what I remember doing.

I did what you recommended and mounted the filesystem successfully.

After adding the elastic ip I faced some abnormalities in the operation of the asterisk and I simply restarted the server. The Instance is unreachable on status check.

My volumes, machines and snapshots were very disorganized, I deleted them all because I just need to add an ip on the machine to almost finalize the project and then do the backups again in a organized way.

I found a case where a person went through something similar and succeeded after removing the elastic ip and rebooting the machine. I tried doing this procedure but it did not work for me.